# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named - while importing a module from another folder

Tags: python, module, directory, path, package

I am getting the famous - `ModuleNotFoundError` when I try to import a module from another folder. Here is the folder structure -

```
packages
   - packageA
     - src
       - packagename
         - app.py <-- imports the readers.reader_module
         - __init__.py
         - readers
           - __init__.py
           - reader_module.py <-- contains a read()
```

The source under `packagename` will be packaged and hence I have added `__init__.py` under it. Similarly, under `readers` folder `__init__.py` is added.

When I import `reader_module` in `app.py` I get - `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packagename'`.

I tried below import statements inside `app.py` but no luck -

- `from packagename.readers.reader_module import read`
- `from .readers.reader_module import read`
- `from readers.reader_module import read`

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I tried to simulate your example and I was able to import  with syntax

```
from readers.reader_module import sum_nums
```